# 0.2V drop in my charging circuit 100A

Tags: diodes

I have a two battery banks on my boat.

The largest in terms of capacity is the house bank, which is made of deep cycle batteries that can be charged at up to 14.82V.

The engine start bank can only be charged at up to 14.7V.

My goal is to charge my house bank at the highest voltage in order to reduce engine run time, and without damaging my engine bank.

My plan is to charge the house bank at 14.82V and use a relay to combine the banks when the alternator is charging.

Can I use a diode with a 0.2V or so forward voltage drop? Would it require a heatsink?

Comment: I doubt there will be a large difference in charge time between charging with 14.82V and 14.7V.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a charge controller going to each battery bank separately, then you'll be fine.

For your diode idea, please draw a schematic so we are absolutely clear what you are attempting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple.  You need to show a link to the battery and charger specs with cable voltage losses.

I suspect your Marine batteries are [AGM](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures) or absorption glass matt.

It may be they both AGM so you just need a battery isolator which is usually a high power dual MOSFET switch to acts as an ideal diode.

The absorption voltage is specified at 25 degrees Celsius for 14.82V. They have an optimal temperature coefficient on this charge and float voltage with a temp. compensation, = -16mV/C to -24mV/C relative to 25'C.

A professional can diagnose if your charging system needs improvement or you can supply the info (Specs or link to datasheet) here.